# Plastic Softening Compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am trying to identify a compound that could be used to soften a Rubic’s Cube’s plastic to make it turn faster and smoother.

I have read that a number of cubers have used a Boron treatment to accomplish this.  Unfortunately Boron is hazardous and I am looking for a safer alternative that would accomplish the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: What about a VR-headset and any Rubik's Cube game made for Oculus or Vive? No physical object, no friction :)

Comment: Don't think that you'd want to "soften" the plastic since that would make it sticky. Rather you'd want to harden and polish the plastic joints.

Comment: I used to use molydisulfide (MoS2) dry lubricant - it worked quite well. Disassemble the cube, lightly coat the interior faces, and reassemble.